# Initialize React Google Maps StandaloneSearchBox with geocode

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

Can someone tell me how to initialize React Google Maps's  StandaloneSearchBox component with types: ['geocode'] (like in the original google.maps.places.Autocomplete, so i can restrict the autocomplete's suggestions of the input?

Comment: I have the same query, Please suggest any solution!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something like this with alexandar's suggestion. Pass an address into the address search and use geocode to do a near by search. Hope this helps.

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from 'recompose';
import { withScriptjs } from 'react-google-maps';
import StandaloneSearchBox from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/places/StandaloneSearchBox';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import head from 'lodash/head';
import { Search } from '../components';

const GOOGLE_API_KEY = '123';

const AddressSearchbox = compose(
  withProps(props => {
    return {
      ...props,
      googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
      loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
      containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    };
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const refs = {};

      this.setState({
        places: [],
        searchText: '',
        error: null,
        onSearchBoxMounted: ref => {
          refs.searchBox = ref;
        },
        onPlacesChanged: () => {
          const places = refs.searchBox.getPlaces();
          this.setState({
            places,
            searchText: '',
          });
        },
      });

      ***
      const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ address: this.props.placeName }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        const lngs = results[0].geometry.bounds.j;
        const lats = results[0].geometry.bounds.l;
        this.setState({
          boundSearch: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(lats.l, lngs.l),
            new google.maps.LatLng(lats.j, lngs.j)
          ),
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          error: status,
        });
      }
      ***
      });
    },
  })
)(props => {
  return (
    <div data-standalone-searchbox="">
      <StandaloneSearchBox
        ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
        onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
        bounds={props.boundSearch}
      >
        <Search searchText={props.searchText} />
      </StandaloneSearchBox>
      <div>{get(head(props.places), 'formatted_address')}</div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default AddressSearchbox;

<AddressSearchbox address="cleveland, oh" />
```

Answer (score 0):

StandaloneSearchBox is a wrapper around google.maps.places.SearchBox.
So Google documentation for SearchBox says that:

> The SearchBox constructor takes two arguments:
>
> - An HTML input element of type text. This is the input field that the
>     SearchBox service will monitor and attach its results to.
> - **An options
>     argument, which can contain the bounds property: bounds is a
>     google.maps.LatLngBounds object specifying the area in which to search
>     for places.** The results are biased towards, but not restricted to,
>     places contained within these bounds.
>
> Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox

So you can call this component like this:

```
<StandaloneSearchBox
      ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
      bounds={props.bounds}
      onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
      defaultBounds={new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655),
            new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544)
      )}
```

Where `defaultBounds` is a [LatLngBounds class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds) which is represents a rectangle in geographical coordinates.